# Where is sun-appserv-ant.jar for Glassfish v3

Tags: glassfish

Where is sun-appserv-ant.jar in Glassfish v3

I have created a small sample EJB project and I want to use ant to deploy the application to Glassfish v3.

Ive spent a lot of time on google trying to achieve this and all ant samples seem to refer to a jar file called "sun-appserv-ant.jar" which is supposed to be located in the modules directory of the application server install, however, I cannot find it anywhere, nor can I seem to find the reason why, or if there is even an ant based alternative.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The sun-appserv-ant.xml file was not brought forward with v3.

You are not completely stuck though.

You can [read about the Ant `exec` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html), which you can use to trigger [asadmin commands](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7701/6nium5vqn?a=expand).

If you are very adventurous, you may want to investigate the bp-project framework that is used by the sample projects that ship with the [Java EE 6 SDK](http://java.sun.com/javaee/downloads/index.jsp).

You can get a peek at the bp-project framework by looking at the code in the [glassfish-samples repository](https://glassfish-samples.dev.java.net/source/browse/glassfish-samples/ws/bp-project/).

Answer (score 3):

You should add the `glassfish-ant-tasks` module through the GlassFish Update Tool

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done that. However sun-appserv-ant.jar was not added to the modules directory under <install path of App Server>/glassfish/modules

Am I missing something

Comment: Its a diffrent jar now ant-tasks.jar, and the interface has changed a little too.
<taskdef name="sun-appserv-deploy"
 classname="org.glassfish.ant.tasks.DeployTask"     
 classpath="${glassfish.dir}/lib/ant/ant-tasks.jar"/>

Comment: As of Glassfish 3.1, the module that you need to add is not "Ant," but "glassfish-ant-tasks"

Answer (score 1):

After much agony I found an example of how to use the V3.x ant tools [here](http://blog.arkzoyd.com/2010/07/deployer-jsf-20-helloworld-sur.html)

The downside, for non-French-speakers, is that it's in French.  The upside is that the Java parts are still in Java.

From what I can tell, the Ant tasks now differ significantly from what is documented by Sun (Oracle):

1. You must use the Glassfish server update tool to get the `glassfish-ant-tasks` module.
2. This will cause the file *glassfish_dir*/lib/ant/ant-tasks.jar to be downloaded.  That must be included on your classpath
3. Define an `as-ant-init` target in your build.xml

   ```
   <target name="as-ant-init">
       <taskdef name="sun-appserv-deploy"
           classname="org.glassfish.ant.tasks.DeployTask"
           classpath="${build-lib}/ant-tasks.jar" />
       <taskdef name="sun-appserv-undeploy"
           classname="org.glassfish.ant.tasks.UndeployTask"
           classpath="${build-lib}/ant-tasks.jar" />
       <taskdef name="sun-appserv-component"
           classname="org.glassfish.ant.tasks.ComponentTask"
           classpath="${build-lib}/ant-tasks.jar" />
       <taskdef name="sun-appserv-admin"
           classname="org.glassfish.ant.tasks.AdminTask"
           classpath="${build-lib}/ant-tasks.jar" />
       <taskdef name="sun-appserv-redeploy"
           classname="org.glassfish.ant.tasks.RedeployTask"
           classpath="${build-lib}/ant-tasks.jar" />
       <taskdef name="sun-appserv-start-server"
           classname="org.glassfish.ant.tasks.StartServerTask"
           classpath="${build-lib}/ant-tasks.jar" />
       <taskdef name="sun-appserv-stop-server"
           classname="org.glassfish.ant.tasks.StopServerTask"
           classpath="${build-lib}/ant-tasks.jar" />
   </target>
   ```
4. Write the deployment target.  The rules are *similar* to what's in the documentation, **EXCEPT**

   A. Remove references to the `<server>` element that was used in older versions.

   B. All of the attributes that would have been attached to `<server>` in the older version of the API are now attached directly to the containing element, such as `<sun-appserv-deploy>`, like so:

   ```
   <target name="deploy">
       <sun-appserv-deploy
           user="${glassfish.admin-user}"
           passwordfile="${glassfish.passwordfile}}"
           host="${glassfish.host}"
           port="${glassfish.admin-port}"
           installDir="${asinstalldir}"
           upload="true" >

           <component
               file="${dist.warfile}"
               name="My application"
               contextroot="${glassfish.context-root}" />
       </sun-appserv-deploy>
   </target>
   ```